# When attempting to add Module this error message appears "Module was compiled using an incompatible version of Kotlin"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle-kotlin-dsl

When I add august aar file (like below ) I am getting this error ***"Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0."***

```
    plugins {
            id 'com.android.application'
            id 'kotlin-android'
            id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
            id 'kotlin-kapt'
            id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
            id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
            id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
        }
    android{
            //..
    }
    dependencies {
            //...other dependencies 
            implementation(files("libs/augustsdk-11.9.0.aar")) //<--
    }
```

My Project level build.gradle file

```
apply from: 'gradle-scripts/dependencies.gradle'
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        //...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.1'
        //...

    }
}
```

If I upgrade the kotlin version to **ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'**
then this error

***The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is no longer supported. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation)***

If I upgrade the kotlin version to **ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.0'**
then this error

***Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0***

I don't get it. What exactly is the issue here? If you then provide the solution.

Thanks :)